# MarkerClusterer class not found, cannot construct a marker cluster

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer, angular-google-maps

I am using "@angular/google-maps": "^17.3.0" in a angular 17 standalone application.
After implementing the `map-marker-clusterer` I am getting error in the browser console.
Error: `Error: MarkerClusterer class not found, cannot construct a marker cluster. Please install the MarkerClustererPlus library: https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus`.

Here's an example of the implemented map:

```
<div class="g-maps">
  @if(!mapsLoading){
  <google-map
    #map
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    [options]="mapMptions"
    (mapClick)="addMarker($event)"
    (mapInitialized)="onMapReady($event)"
  >
    <map-marker-clusterer>
      @for (position of markerPositions; track position) {
      <map-advanced-marker [position]="position" />
      }
    </map-marker-clusterer>
  </google-map>
  }
</div>
```